# Carpool ID not fetching from my API properly

Tags: node.js, swift, function, express

I am making a join group function that enables a user to join a group once they input in a join code. This is my api route:

```
app.post('/api/joinGroup/:carpool_id', express.json(), async (req, res) => {
const result = joinGroupSchema.validate(req.body);

if (result.error) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: result.error.details[0].message });
}

const carpoolID = req.params.carpool_id;
const firebaseUserID = req.body.firebase_user_id;
console.log(carpoolID)
console.log(firebaseUserID)
try {
    console.log('Join Group Request Body:', req.body);

    const groupId = parseInt(carpoolID);

    // Check if the group (carpool) exists
    const groupExists = carpools.some(c => c.carpoolID === groupId);
    if (!groupExists) {
        console.log('Group does not exist:', groupId);
        return res.status(404).json({ error: 'The group with the given ID was not found.' });
    }

    // Check if the user is already a member of the group
    const userExistsInGroup = await db.query('SELECT 1 FROM user_carpools WHERE firebase_user_id = $1 AND carpool_id = $2', [firebaseUserID, groupId]);
    if (userExistsInGroup.rows.length > 0) {
        console.log('User is already a member of the group:', firebaseUserID, groupId);
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'User is already a member of the group.' });
    }

    // Add user to the group
    const addUserToGroupQuery = 'INSERT INTO user_carpools(firebase_user_id, carpool_id) VALUES ($1, $2)';
    await db.query(addUserToGroupQuery, [firebaseUserID, groupId]);

    console.log('User added to the group successfully:', firebaseUserID, groupId);
    return res.status(200).json({ message: 'User added to the group successfully' });
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
} };
```

Now using this route I am making my joingroup function:

```
 func joingroup(carpoolID: String, firebaseUserID: String, completion: @escaping (Result<Void, Error>) -> Void) {
    Task {
        do {
            // Assuming you have the API endpoint URL for joining a group
            let apiUrlString = "http://localhost/api/joinGroup/\(carpoolID)"
            guard let apiUrl = URL(string: apiUrlString) else {
                // Handle the case where the URL is not valid
                completion(.failure(WebService.NetworkError.invalidRequest))
                return
            }

            // Create the request body
            let requestBody: [String: Any] = ["firebase_user_id": firebaseUserID]

            // Convert the request body to Data
            guard let requestData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestBody) else {
                completion(.failure(WebService.NetworkError.invalidRequest))
                return
            }

            // Make the request
            var request = URLRequest(url: apiUrl)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.httpBody = requestData

            do {
                let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)

                guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                    completion(.failure(WebService.NetworkError.invalidResponse))
                    return
                }

                print("HTTP Response Status Code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")

                if !(200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) {
                    print("Error: Invalid HTTP response status code \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                    if let responseData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) {
                        print("Response Data: \(responseData)")
                    }
                    completion(.failure(WebService.NetworkError.invalidResponse))
                    return
                }

                // Refresh the list of groups (you might need to adjust this based on your app's architecture)
                do {
                    let groups = try await self.webService.getCarpoolGroups(url: URL(string: "http://localhost/api/carpools")!)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.groups = groups.map(GroupViewModel.init)
                        completion(.success(()))
                    }
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }

            } catch {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
}
```

Now I try to use it on my swiftUI page:

```
struct JoinGroup: View {
@StateObject private var vm = GroupsListViewModel()
@State private var joinCode: String = ""
@State private var showAlert: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack(spacing: 5) {
                    Text("Join Code")
                        .bold()
                }
                TextField("Enter Join Code", text: $joinCode)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .background {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .frame(height: 57)
                            .foregroundColor(Color("rectColor"))
                    }
                    .padding(.top)
            }
            .padding(.top)

            Button {
                if isEnabled() {
                    joinGroup()
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Join Group")
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(isEnabled() ?
                        Color.blue.cornerRadius(10) : Color.secondary.cornerRadius(10))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
                getAlert()
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Join Group")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
        .padding()
        .padding(.horizontal, 5)
    }
}

func isEnabled() -> Bool {
    return !joinCode.isEmpty
}

func clearFields() {
    joinCode = ""
}

func getAlert() -> Alert {
    return Alert(
        title: Text("Successfully Joined Group"),
        message: Text("You have successfully joined the group with the join code: \(joinCode)"),
        dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"))
    )
}

func joinGroup() {
    // Unwrap the optional firebaseUserID
    if let firebaseUserID = getCurrentUserFirebaseUserID() {
        // Assuming vm is your ViewModel instance
        vm.joingroup(carpoolID: joinCode, firebaseUserID: firebaseUserID) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success:
                showAlert = true
                // Additional actions upon success
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error joining group: \(error)")
            }
        }
    } else {
        return
    }
}
```

Finally this is the error I receive:

```
 Error: Invalid HTTP response status code 400
Response Data: {
    error = "\"carpoolid\" is required";
}
Error joining group: invalidResponse
```

The things that I have tried to fix this is ensure my api url is correct and make a bunch of console.logs. However, I am not sure whether the error is because it cannot access my carpoolid or my firebase user id or both. This is the function I use to get my firebase user id:

```
 func getCurrentUserFirebaseUserID() -> String? {
    if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        let firebaseUserID = currentUser.uid
        return firebaseUserID
    } else {
        // No user is signed in
        return nil
    }
}
```

}

Any help would be much appreciated thank you so much in advance!